# Return value from modal dialog (application page) to toolpart

Tags: modal-dialog, application-pages, toolpart

I have a Webpart with an ToolPart. In this ToolPart I open an ModalDialog displaying a List. When pressing Submit-Button or something like this, in the ModalDialog, I want to return a String to the ToolPart.
How do I get the value, Code-Behind, in the ToolPart?

I tried different stuff

Per Javascript, but hiddenvalues aren't possible in ToolPart.
Or per WebpartManager. But nothing helped.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
function findListClick(){

   var textboxId = //your textBoxID to set callBack string
   LaunchPickerTreeDialog("CbqPickerSelectSiteTitle", "CbqPickerSelectSiteTitle", "listsOnly", "", webUrl, null, "", "", "", 0,        
   function(results){
       if (results == null || results == undefined || results[1] == null)
            return;

            var textbox = document.getElementById(textboxId);
            textbox.value = webUrl + results[3];
       }
   });
}
```

see [full code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bhushangawale/sharepointmoss-2007-picker-tree-dialog/)